# Slashes in expression in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I get url like this 'http://mysite.pl/public?products,BEER/7,shop_shelf' and I want to rewrite it into http://mysite.pl/index.php?product=BEER/7 in .htaccess.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at writing a pattern? Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Yes i get some think like this: 
'RewriteRule ^products,([a-zA-Z\.\+a-z0-9-_/]*),([a-zA-Z\.\+a-z0-9-]+))$ index.php?product=$1 [L,B,NC]'

Answer (score 1):

Everything after a question mark is query string, and `RewriteRule` directive works only with  substitution string. You should use `RewriteCond` instead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products,([-/_\.a-z0-9]*?),[-/_\.a-z0-9]+$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^public$ index.php?product=%1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'RewriteRule ^products,([a-zA-Z\.\+a-z0-9-_/]*),([a-zA-Z\.\+a-z0-9-]+))$ index.php?product=$1 [L,B,NC]
```

Few problems I can see there, you're not checking for "public?" at the beginning, I think you're confusing your alphabets up too.

```
RewriteRule ^public\?products,([a-zA-Z\.\+-_]+)\/([0-9]+),([a-zA-Z-_]+)$
```

Try something like that, I've just written it quickly without testing though. It should check for a string starting with `public?products,` followed by a subpattern consisting of 1 or more of the characters `[a-zA-Z\.\+-_]` (This would be `$1` in your target), followed by `/` followed by another subpattern consisting of one or more of the characters `[0-9]` (`$2`) followed by `,` followed finally by another subpattern containing the characters `[a-zA-Z-_]` (`$3` if you need it)

Like I said, I've not tested it so just start with that and play about with it